# как сохранить синглтон при выходе из приложения iOs

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

Я использую синглтон класса. Синглтон хранит десяток переменных и архивы. Это работает отлично. Нужно сохранять его (sharedWar) при выходе и загружать при следующем запуске игры. Как использовать NSCode не разобрался. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо!

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class War: SKScene {

static var sharedWar = War(size.size)
...

}
```

**Обновление**

Я не рассматривал NSUserDefaults как способ сохранения SKScene. Исходник на SWIFT - можно ли на нем?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Можно заархивировать объекты с помощью NSCoding и засунуть в NSUserDefaults. В этой [статье](https://blog.soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding) подробно все объясняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший способ - использовать `NSUserDefaults`. Тут можно хранить любые структуры их простых данных (числа, строки, коллекции, даты, NSDate).

```
- (void)save {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@{@"x" : @(self.x), @"y" : @(self.y)} forKey:@"WarKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)load {
    NSDictionary *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"WarKey"];
    if (data == nil) {
        self.x = DEFAULT_X;
        self.y = DEFAULT_Y;
    } else {
        self.x = [data[@"x"] intValue];
        self.y = [data[@"y"] intValue];
    }
}
```

Вызывать save нужно перед завергением приложения, но лучше делать это чаще, по возможность - при каждом изменении данных, так как при краше приложения на ошибке will terminate вызван не будет. Ну load - соответственно при старте приложения.

**Обновление**

Он может записать набор полей, или, например, json-строку. Этот метод не deprecated. Его недостаток в том, что объект (в нашем случае - словарь с данными объекта War) в нём храниться одним куском данных и для перезаписи придётся переписывать весь объект полностью. Содержание user defaults по уровню приватности приравнивается к папке Documents, если не ошибаюсь можно даже синкать его через клауд. Конечно, правильнее делать через CoreData, но всё зависит от сложности и количества данных. Если ух будет 10-20 полей - то заюзать дефалтсы тут будет отличной и удобной альтернативой CoreData.

Comment: NSUserDefaults не может сохранять экземпляр класса, в данном случае - синглтон static var sharedWar = War(size.size). В Вашем предложении сохраняется значение для инициализации, а нужно сохранить значение всех переменных и содержание архивов в синглтоне на момент закрытия приложения. Это описано в предварительном условии.

Comment: В предварительном условии было сказало про `NSCoder`. Он не сохраняет экземпляр, его тоже реализовывать как протокол и поштучно загонять необходимые поля. Сериализации на физическом уровне для объектов не предусмотрено, так как есть принципиально несериализируемые сущности, например потоки. Задача выбора полей (и их подготовка) для сериализации ложиться на программиста. Можно использовать  сторонние библиотеки, которые будут пробегаться по всем полям и запоминать их, но по факту в результате получится тот же словарь или `NSData`, который надо где-то хранить.

Comment: @ markov Спасибо большое! Я понял, что иного пути, как только поштучно сохранять все нужные данные нет. Ужасно.

Comment: Это не ужасно, это вполне себе норм. Объект - это не структура, у которой всё, что хранится является данными, у объекта есть служебные поля и пр. Даже сериализация в яве требует, чтобы все поля были сериализируемыми, а правильная сериализация подразумевает, что программист пропишет аннотации и выбеерет поля, которые нужно сериализировать. Но вообще - CoreData - это оно и есть, то, что тебе надо, хранишь там один объект, сохраняешь когда надо и всё, все поля, который из коре дата оно будет сохранять. Только тогда самому надо быть экземпляром этого класса.

Comment: Насколько я понял, Sprite Kit c CoreData не работает. При создании проекта даже не спрашивает про использование CoreData (

Answer (score 0):

Вы легко сможете сохранить и достать данные используя например Realm. Просто CoreData имеет большой стэк настроек и для вашего вопроса будет слишком громоздким решением, а вот Realm настраивается очень быстро и будет удобен для сохранении/загрузки нужной модели. 
Конечно можно использовать NSCoding, но все же это разные вещи, решать вам.
Подробнее про Realm можете почитать тут: 
https://realm.io

Comment: Realm - это сторонний сервер? Но он не работает при отсутствии доступа к сети. Это недопустимо.

Comment: Эмм, Realm - это кросс-платформенная мобильная база данных для iOS.

Comment: Вот статейка на хабре: [ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/272393/)

Comment: Разобрался)) Спасибо! Интересная вещь

Comment: то, что у него integration size 108 мегабайт, никого не смущает?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ты про Realm?

Comment: да, я про realm. и здесь принято на вы

Comment: REALM - простой и легкий, но сторонний - для него нужен CocoaPods. CoreDATA - сложнее и тяжелее, зато это нативный компонент: написал Import CoreData, и все! (почти :)